# Query builder didn't find data when using %

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to use query builder in controller using laravel, and i don't understand but the query didn't find the data.

Here's the code:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = downloads::all();

    if(request('searchName')){
        $data = $data->where('fileName','like','%'.request('searchName').'%'); //Here's the problem
        return view('download', compact('data'));
    }
    else{
        return view('download', compact('data'));
    }
}
```

i already tried `dd(request('searchName'))` and it display the input that i give, so there's no problem here

when I'm using `$data->where('fileName','like','%'.request('searchName').'%')` there's no data shown

i don't think that i misspell the fileName because when I'm using `$data->where('fileName','like',request('searchName'))` and it worked and display the file, but the fileName must be exactly the same as the inputed searchName, and of course what i wanted is not this

even when I'm using `dd('%'.request('searchName').'%');` it will display `"%*searchName*%"` that's why i so confused when it didn't work when I'm using `$data->where('fileName','like','%'.request('searchName').'%');`

I even using `SELECT * FROM *tables* WHERE fileName LIKE '%p%';` in SQL Workbench and it worked perfectly fine

Any suggestion of what should i do? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks odd. Why are you filtering the collection instead of adding the `where` conditional in your query?

Imagine you have thousands of `download` records but the where condition just match with a few ones, you will be fetching everything just for showing some of them.

IMO, a better approach should be

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = downloads::
    when($request->has('searchName'), function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('fileName','like','%'.$request->searchName.'%');
    })
    ->get();

    return view('download', compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: this solve my problem too, both answer from @John Lobo and you worked fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`all()` is static method not query builder.If you see internal of `all()` code then its calling get method

```
 /**
     * Get all of the models from the database.
     *
     * @param  array|mixed  $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */
    public static function all($columns = ['*'])
    {
        return static::query()->get(
            is_array($columns) ? $columns : func_get_args()
        );
    }
```

There are few ways to solve this .

```
public function index()
{
    $downloads = downloads::query();

    if(!empty(request('searchName'))){
     $downloads->where('fileName','like','%'.request('searchName').'%'); 
       
    }
   
    $data=$downloads->get();
     return view('download', compact('data'));
}
```

or

```
public function index()
{
    $data = downloads::when(!empty(request('searchName')),function($query){
            $query->where('fileName','like','%'.request('searchName').'%');
    })->get();

   
    return view('download', compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: It worked fine, thanks for the help and knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply your querystring with like in a collection. In a collection, you can use the filter($callback_function) method to select elements in the collection. Pass a callback function that returns true for each element to be returned.

In your case, you can use the stristr() function to emulate a LIKE operator, something like this:

```
collect($data)->filter(function ($item) use ($searchName) {
    return false !== stristr($item->fileName, $searchName);
});
```